# Proving projection map is onto

Tags: equivalence-relations

> Let $X$ be a nonempty set and let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $X.$ Given $X/R={[a]:a \in X}$. **Prove that there is a map called the projection where $p_x:X\to X/R$ given by $p_x(t)=[t].$ Then this map is onto (surjective).**

I know that by definition: Let $X$ be a nonempty set and let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. The set of all equivalence classes, ${[a]:a\in X},$ is called the Quotient Set of $X$ modulo $R,$ written as $X/R.$

I am trying to teach this to myself. I spoke to a friend of mine who made me want to learn some of this. It seemed good to know. How would I prove that the projection map is onto given this nonempty set and equivalence relation. Can someone please help me? It would be nice if I can have a conversation with my friend showing him what I learned on this.

Comment: I wouldn't call this the projection map. Maybe the quotient map.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry. I was not sure what the proper name of this map would be. I did some research and they called it projection map in the question. Can you help me prove this?

Comment: The projection map is from a Cartesian product onto one of the coordinates. This is a quotient map, since we "divide" by the equivalence relation, and it is somewhat like a quotient. As for helping, you have an answer. I would have left a short hint: use reflexivity of the relation.

Answer (score 2):

Take any equivalence class (and denote it $\mathscr c$) of $X/R$ so by the definition of the equivalence relation $\mathscr c$ isn't empty. Let $a\in\mathscr c$ then we have

$$p_X(a)=\mathscr c$$ 
hence $p_X$ is onto.

Comment: Is there a more explanatory proof? If so, can you show it to me?

Comment: What's you didn't understand in this proof?

Comment: I understood the proof. I didn't expect it to be that short though. I looked at some other proofs of other problems that went were like this and it was long with details.

Comment: Is there any way we could show transitivity and symmetry from this using reflexivity

Comment: Transitivity and symmetry of what?

Comment: I got another problem mixed up with this problem. I was just trying to compare what I learned after teaching myself this.

Comment: I think this is the proof I am looking for. It seems correct. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!